# CFML Jquery Ajax - returns zero when cffunction actually returns 18

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

This has to be a Jquery question.  The following code is returning zero.  When I test/debug, I can say without a doubt that the cffunction is generating the number 18.
The success alert shows "Dupe Group-2 count=0".  The Firebug response shows;
{"COLUMNS":["DUPECOUNTER"],"DATA":[["0"]]}

```
  if ($(e.target).is(":checked")) {
    $firstTD = $(this).parent().siblings().first();
    SaveDupeGroup = $firstTD.text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'cfc/basic.cfc?method=CheckDupeGroup&returnformat=json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'dupegrouptocheck=' + $firstTD.text(),
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error 
            alert(errorThrown); 
            },
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('Dupe Group-' + SaveDupeGroup + ' count=' + response.DATA[0]);
            ReInitAnswer = confirm('All of the names in this group have been checked.\nDo you want to remove them from the list?');
        if (ReInitAnswer) {
              alert('continued'); 
                } else {
              alert('canceled');
              return false;
                }
        }
            });
        }

<cffunction name="CheckDupeGroup" output="false" access="remote">
<cfargument name="DupeGroupNumber" required="True" type="string" default="" />
<cfset var qResults = "" />
<cfquery name="qResults" datasource="#request.dsn#">
SELECT COUNT(id) AS DupeCounter 
FROM Temp_Duplicate_Individuals_AddressZipState 
Where dupe_group_number = #val(arguments.DupeGroupNumber)# and isnull(not_dupe_flag,'False') = 'False' 
</cfquery>
<cfreturn (qResults) />
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `data: 'dupegrouptocheck=' + $firstTD.text()`, but the argument name in the function is `DupeGroupNumber`. Change `dupegrouptocheck` to `DupeGroupNumber`.

The reason this isn't throwing a required argument error is because you have a default value (an empty string) for the argument, and CF will use the default value rather than throwing an error for not passing in the argument.

So, you are essentially running:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS DupeCounter 
FROM Temp_Duplicate_Individuals_AddressZipState 
Where dupe_group_number = "" and isnull(not_dupe_flag,'False') = 'False'
```

Because you don't have a `dupe_group_number` that equals `""`, the query is correctly returning a count of 0.

Comment: Good Catch.  You wouldn't believe how long I've been looking at this. I've spent days trying to figure out why CF was sending so much html with the response.  I guess my eyes were blurry.

Comment: Eh, just lucky I've been working with CF/AJAX so much lately. :) As a side note, I'd recommend removing the default value from required arguments to prevent stuff like this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the argument you are sending is incorrect.  Inspect the get call

Answer (score -1):

It's Asynchronous, that's why. Your code is doing the return before the data is retuned from your server. at the point of "if(ReInitAnswer)", ReInitAnswer is not even there. Generally, in functions that includes an ajax call, you don't return something, instead, you would change something on the page or change a state.

By the way, you should var your js variables

EDIT: Oh sorry, the return statement was in the success call (the indentation was a bit confusing :p). In this case it's still the same, your parent function has already finished before the ajax call success function does the return. therefore the returned value will always be wrong.

Comment: Isn't that why I put the alert in the success function? I understood that the success function is waiting for completion.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Regardless of what the jQuery is doing after the response is received, he is still getting a response from CF(`{"COLUMNS":["DUPECOUNTER"],"DATA":[["0"]]}`) that indicates that the query is returning a count of 0.

Comment: yeah, but the return from your function will never be at the correct "time"